# How can we check if the user is deleted or not using facebook Id?

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-ui, facebook-graph-api

I want to hide facebook account deleted user's profile image from the site. I am binding image using jQuery,

```
items += '<a href=https://facebook.com/' + fbId + ' target="_blank"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + fbId + '/picture" title=' + fbName + '>' + '</a>';
                    $(".profile-icon").append(items);
```

I have facebook id, using that facebook id how can we check if the user is deleted or not (active/not active) using jQuery/javascript.

How to hide deleted facebook user's profile image from the site ? How can we check user is still active or not with facebook userid using jQuery

Comment: This does not seem to have any elements that use `jquery-ui`. Please provide sample code that may include what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Twisty I have no idea ... i have saved user's facebook userid and iam displaying their profile image using above code. I want to hide image if the user is deleted his/her account.